# Persist login in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I've set up a login endpoint using `rest_auth`'s endpoint. However, after login, if I refresh the page the login is invalidated.

I've tested this by setting up a `/loginCheck' endpoint which I check after logging in as follows:

```
@api_view(['GET',])
@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
def get_user(request):
    user = request.user
    print(user)
```

After logging, if I stay on the page and perform a `/loginCheck',` the print command displays the username of the active user. However, on refresh of page, if I perform the same function, it prints `AnonymousUser`. I've used the following Authentication Classes

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
   ),
)
```

I'm using `TokenAuthentication` as I also have a successfully persisting Facebook login endpoint in my SPA. What am I missing in terms of the persistent non-Facebook login?

EDIT:

My settings middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Do you have both SessionMiddleware and AuthenticationMiddleware in your settings?

Comment: @user640916, I've added my Middleware_classes to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you login with a token, it will only be valid for that single request-respone cycle. By design it is not meant to be persistent like the regular Django browser sessions. So for any subsequent requests you need to attach the value of the token yourself. Retrieving it from a cookie or depending on your client application store it by other means.

Here some example code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
request.open("GET", "foo/bar", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you said you're using the token authentication system however I cant see it in your default authentication classes and your permission classes.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

I think IsAuthenticated is good enough but you should also check other permissions as well; http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated .

My installed apps also contain the authtoken as installed (I am not sure if this is necessary as I had written it some while ago).

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ...
}
```

Hope these help.